# Screen process hangs in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gnu-screen

I'm trying to run screen (version 4.0) in the latest version of Cygwin under 64-bit Windows Ultimate, and it doesn't want to work. I launch a new screen session using "screen -d -m -S screen1". When I connect to it using something like "screen -A -d -r screen1" the process hangs. When I list screens with "screen -list" it reports the screen as "possibly Dead".

Any idea how to get screen working in my environment?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran the same commands you did, and had similar problems.  But I use screen under 64-bit Windows 7 all the time.

I just use `screen` to start a screen session, and `screen -dr` to reattach to the same session later.  (I've actually been using `screen -U` and `screen -drU`, but I just realized that with `defutf8 on` in my `$HOME/.screenrc`, the `-U` isn't necessary.)

I haven't figured out why your approach doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used "screen -U -S screen1" to create a new session and successfully connected to it with "screen -drU screen1." This should be all I need. I'll leave it to the cygwin folks to fix the other options.

Answer (score 1):

I am also currently trying to get screen work on a cygwin installation on a windows server 2008 installation.

it works in principle, so I can reuse sessions, but its quite buggy:

1.) only sessions started through an rdp session (on the windows desktop) are able to access mounted network shares, sessions started through ssh can only access "c". (okey not really a screen bug, more cygwin in general)

2.) detach doesn't work through ssh. strg+a+d just freezes the terminal, by using these keys in that sequence: [strg+z, bg, %, strg+c] I can get back into the screen session I've last visited.

3.) this leads to the funny state that I can have the same screen session attached multiple times, and see the input and output on all instances